# xfce4-terminal goes 'blank' occasionally while in drop-down mode

Tags: xfce4, xfce4-terminal

It happens whilst I hit my keyboard shortcut to access the terminal.  The window responds to mouse and keyboard input, but it will not draw itself properly.  The only way to restore the terminal is to quit the program and restart it.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/aPYEMP3.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved it.  I eliminated the drop-down animation duration and the problem hasn't come back.  I'll mark this as answered for now.